# Cypher: Calculate based on node properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I develop a routing system to find the best routes by using several mobility offers, e. g. public transport or car pooling.
Basically I have nodes, that represent bus stops, train stops etc. These stops include time schedules for each day. Additionally I have pedestrian stops. These stops are connected by relations. If I change from pedestrian to bus, or between bus lines, the relation is called SWITCH_TO. If I drive several stops without changing the service line, the stops are connected by a relation called CONNECTED_TO. If I want to go from point A to point Z and I have to change at bus stop C to another service line at bus stop D the path would look like this:

```
(A:Stop:Pedestrian)-[SWITCH_TO{switchTime:2}]->
(A:Stop:Bus{serviceLine:1})-[CONNECTED_TO{travelTime:5}]->
(B:Stop:Bus{serviceLine:1})-[CONNECTED_TO{travelTime:6}]->
(C:Stop:Bus{serviceLine:1})-[SWITCH_TO{switchTime:2}]->
(C:Stop:Pedestrian)-[CONNECTED_TO{travelTime:7}]->
(D:Stop:Pedestrian)-[SWITCH_TO{switchTime:2}]->
(D:Stop:Bus{serviceLine:2})-[CONNECTED_TO{travelTime:8}]->(Z:Stop:Bus{serviceLine:2})-[SWITCH_TO{switchTime:2}]->
(Z:Stop:Pedestrian)
```

I want to calculate based on a desired departure time (alternatively a desired arrival time) of the user the full travel time and get the 5 best connections (less time). 
In the example above you can see, that the SWITCH_TO relation has a switchTime of 2. This means that I need 2 minutes to switch from the current place to the bus stop (e.g. I have to look for it). The CONNECTED_TO relation travelTimes are the time periods, that the bus needs to go from one stop to another.
Lets assume that I want to start at 7:00. The first switch needs 2 minutes. Therefore I have to look at the schedule of (A:Stop:Bus) if there is a departure after 7:02. Lets assume the next departure is at 7:10. then I have to wait 8 minutes. This waiting time is no fixed value but a variable time period for each specific request. I start at 7:10. I need 5+6=11 minutes to go to stop (C:Stop:Bus) and 2 minutes to go off the bus (switch to). Then I have to go 7 minutes by foot. So if have to check the schedule of service line 2. If there is a departure after 7:00+2+8+5+6+2+7+2 = 7:32, take this. If the next departure is at 7:35 I will reach my destination at 7:00+2+8+5+6+2+7+2+3+8+2= 7:45. I know, I bit complex. :)

I prepared an example here:

```
CREATE (newStop:Stop:Pedestrian {
    stopName : 'A-Pedestrian',
    mode : 'Pedestrian'
})
RETURN newStop;

CREATE (newStop:Stop:Bus {
    stopName : 'A-Bus',
    mode : 'Bus',
    serviceLine : '1',
    monday:[510,610,710,810,835,910],
    tuesday:[510,610,710,810,835,910],
    wednesday:[510,610,710,810,835,910],
    thursday:[510,610,710,810,835,910],
    friday:[510,610,710,810,835,910],
    saturday:[510,610,710,810,835,910],
    sunday:[510,610,710,810,835,910]
})
RETURN newStop;

CREATE (newStop:Stop:Bus {
    stopName : 'B-Bus',
    mode : 'Bus',
    serviceLine : '1',
    monday:[515,615,715,815,840,915],
    tuesday:[515,615,715,815,840,915],
    wednesday:[515,615,715,815,840,915],
    thursday:[515,615,715,815,840,915],
    friday:[515,615,715,815,840,915],
    saturday:[515,615,715,815,840,915],
    sunday:[515,615,715,815,840,915]
})
RETURN newStop;

CREATE (newStop:Stop:Bus {
    stopName : 'C-Bus',
    mode : 'Bus',
    serviceLine : '1',
    monday:[521,621,711,821,846,921],
    tuesday:[521,621,711,821,846,921],
    wednesday:[521,621,711,821,846,921],
    thursday:[521,621,711,821,846,921],
    friday:[521,621,711,821,846,921],
    saturday:[521,621,711,821,846,921],
    sunday:[521,621,711,821,846,921]
})
RETURN newStop;

CREATE (newStop:Stop:Pedestrian {
    stopName : 'C-Pedestrian',
    mode : 'Pedestrian'
})
RETURN newStop;

CREATE (newStop:Stop:Pedestrian {
    stopName : 'D-Pedestrian',
    mode : 'Pedestrian'
})
RETURN newStop;

CREATE (newStop:Stop:Bus {
    stopName : 'D-Bus',
    mode : 'Bus',
    serviceLine : '2',
    monday:[535,635,735,835,935],
    tuesday:[535,635,735,835,935],
    wednesday:[535,635,735,835,935],
    thursday:[535,635,735,835,935],
    friday:[535,635,735,835,935],
    saturday:[535,635,735,835,935],
    sunday:[]
})
RETURN newStop;

CREATE (newStop:Stop:Bus {
    stopName : 'Z-Bus',
    mode : 'Bus',
    serviceLine : '2',
    monday:[543,643,743,843,943],
    tuesday:[543,643,743,843,943],
    wednesday:[543,643,743,843,943],
    thursday:[543,643,743,843,943],
    friday:[543,643,743,843,943],
    saturday:[543,643,743,843,943],
    sunday:[]
})
RETURN newStop;

CREATE (newStop:Stop:Pedestrian {
    stopName : 'Z-Pedestrian',
    mode : 'Pedestrian'
})
RETURN newStop;




MATCH (s1:Stop), (s2:Stop)
WHERE s1.stopName = 'A-Pedestrian' AND s2.stopName = 'A-Bus'
CREATE
    (s1)-[r:SWITCH_TO{ switchTime : 2 } ]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2, r;

MATCH (s1:Stop), (s2:Stop)
WHERE s1.stopName = 'A-Bus' AND s2.stopName = 'B-Bus'
CREATE
    (s1)-[r:CONNECTED_TO{ travelTime : 5 } ]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2, r;

MATCH (s1:Stop), (s2:Stop)
WHERE s1.stopName = 'B-Bus' AND s2.stopName = 'C-Bus'
CREATE
    (s1)-[r:CONNECTED_TO{ travelTime : 6 } ]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2, r;

MATCH (s1:Stop), (s2:Stop)
WHERE s1.stopName = 'C-Bus' AND s2.stopName = 'C-Pedestrian'
CREATE
    (s1)-[r:SWITCH_TO{ switchTime : 2 } ]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2, r;

MATCH (s1:Stop), (s2:Stop)
WHERE s1.stopName = 'C-Pedestrian' AND s2.stopName = 'D-Pedestrian'
CREATE
    (s1)-[r:CONNECTED_TO{ travelTime : 7 } ]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2, r;

MATCH (s1:Stop), (s2:Stop)
WHERE s1.stopName = 'D-Pedestrian' AND s2.stopName = 'D-Bus'
CREATE
    (s1)-[r:SWITCH_TO{ switchTime : 2 } ]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2, r;

MATCH (s1:Stop), (s2:Stop)
WHERE s1.stopName = 'D-Bus' AND s2.stopName = 'Z-Bus'
CREATE
    (s1)-[r:CONNECTED_TO{ travelTime : 8 } ]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2, r;

MATCH (s1:Stop), (s2:Stop)
WHERE s1.stopName = 'Z-Bus' AND s2.stopName = 'Z-Pedestrian'
CREATE
    (s1)-[r:SWITCH_TO{ switchTime : 2 } ]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2, r;
```

As you can see, in some stops, the int array of departure times could be empty too (if no connection is provided on these days). Pedestrian stops dont include an schedule of course.
My question is: How can I do this query by cypher? I have to sum up these times to choose the correct next departure time. I have to know when I am at my destination. And I want to show the user the best 5 connections. Is there a way to do this? If not, any suggestions how to solve this?

Thank you very much!
Stefan

Edit1:  Is there a way to develop this in Java? In the simplest case it could be just one shortest path but with an intelligent cost function? Instead of using fix values using a function to calculate the cost of one specific edge? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The values for your departure schedules are going to be problematic. You are trying to capture and use time values (515 representing 5:15, for example, or at least that's how it seems to me) but you're working with integers. As it stands now, your calculations with time are not going to automatically roll over to the next hour as you exceed every 60 minutes. Times start getting ambiguous. If we start at 846 (8:46) and a trip takes 50 minutes, we get 896 (9:36). But if we make another connection that takes 5 minutes, we get 901. Is that 9:01 or 9:41? Tracking rollover is problematic.

Comment: Thats correct. I was thinking quite a while because of that. My idea was just to divide by 100 and calculate the hours and minutes separately. But of course its not a very sophisticated solution. It cause additional problems when you have to calculate between to days, e.g. from 23:00 - 00:30.  But any better idea is is appreciated.

Comment: I'd advise adding APOC Procedures to your db, and you may want to read up on its [date/time support](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_date_time_support).

Comment: How could I realize this via APOC? There is still the same problem that I dont know how to start. Do you have an rough idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apologies in advance, this turned into a Russian novel when I wasn't looking. And it will still only get you the single fastest route, not the 5 fastest, but hopefully someone smarter than I can improve on this.]

You are trying to do some fiendishly complex pathing based on a difficult-to-calculate cost . You are definitely going to need to refactor some so that you can fix the cost a little more tightly, and then apply `apoc.algo.dijkstra` to get a viable path with weight. To do that, you're going to need to change from your very general model to some kind of event "chain", organized by physical location. The transit modes combined with the weekly schedule will provide you with some structure here; the ability to walk between locations will complicate it only moderately. Along the way, we'll end up stripping out some of the less-relevant and redundant nodes. Let's dig in.

First things first, we need to be able to convert your times into something machine-parseable. You can use `apoc` to convert them to `isoformat` or similar, but for cyclical times that will require frequent ordering, and only exist at the minute scale, I say start counting midnight on Sunday morning as minute 0 and then count your way up from there. So, minutes-since-Sunday-midnight would be your time of concern, basically, and then with some tricks later you can handle the cyclical part.

```
MATCH (stop:Stop:Bus)
WITH stop, ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'] AS days
UNWIND RANGE(0, 6) AS day_index
WITH stop, day_index, days[day_index] AS day_key
UNWIND stop[day_key] AS int_time
WITH stop, day_index * 24 * 60 AS day_minutes, int_time % 100 AS minutes, ((int_time - (int_time % 100))/100)*60 AS hour_minutes 
WHERE day_minutes IS NOT NULL
WITH stop, day_minutes + hour_minutes + minutes AS time_since_sunday
MERGE (dep:Departure:Bus {time: time_since_sunday})
MERGE (dep) - [:AT] -> (stop)
WITH stop, time_since_sunday
ORDER BY time_since_sunday
WITH stop, collect(time_since_sunday) AS times
SET stop.departure_times = times
```

Alright, that gives us departure events around each bus stop that represent times at which you can start a fixed-length trip elsewhere, if you are at the station before that time. Now, if we were only accounting for transit-based movement, we could connect each `:Departure` node at one `:Stop` to whatever `:Departure` node was available at the next stop after the transit time had elapsed (and account for wait time). Adding in walking (multi-mode transport) changes this a bit, though, since whenever transit arrives somewhere, you can just "depart" on your own two feet instantly. So, we should model `:Arrival` nodes to correspond to the other end of `:Departure` based trips, so that we can differentiate between waiting for the next transit-based `:Departure` and walking, time-wise.

```
MATCH (stop:Stop:Bus) <- [:AT] - (dep:Departure:Bus)
WITH stop, dep, dep.time AS dep_time
MATCH (stop) - [r:CONNECTED_TO] -> (other:Stop:Bus)
WITH dep, dep_time, dep_time + r.travelTime AS arrival_time, other
MERGE (a:Arrival:Bus {time: arrival_time})
MERGE (a) - [:AT] -> (other)
MERGE (dep) - [:TRAVEL {time: arrival_time - dep_time, mode: 'Bus'}] -> (a)
WITH a, arrival_time, other, other.departure_times AS dep_times
WITH a, other, arrival_time, REDUCE(s = HEAD(dep_times), x IN TAIL(dep_times) | CASE WHEN x < arrival_time THEN s WHEN s < x THEN s ELSE x END) AS next_dep_time
WITH a, other, next_dep_time, next_dep_time - arrival_time AS wait_time
MATCH (other) <- [:AT] - (next_dep:Departure:Bus {time: next_dep_time})
MERGE (a) - [:TRAVEL {time: wait_time, mode: 'Wait'}] -> (next_dep)
```

Alright, so for each individual line of transit, we can now calculate how long it will take to get from A to B on that line of transit alone, even if the travel is non-continuous (train hangs out at a stop, etc.) Now the fun part: integrating the walking option! The idea of a "pedestrian stop" doesn't make a lot of sense (unless you are modelling all relevant discrete space, in which case good luck and godspeed), so we're basically going to drop them entirely. A `:SWITCH_TO` that operates between two non-pedestrian stops will just be modeled as walking between the two stops, while a `:SWITCH_TO` a pedestrian transit will be converted to a long walk combining both switches and the walk itself. First the easy ones (which are not in your sample paths, but I think will be valuable to you eventually):

```
MATCH (stop:Stop:Bus) - [r:SWITCH_TO] -> (other:Stop)
WHERE NOT other:Pedestrian
WITH stop, other, r.switchTime AS walking_time, other.departure_times AS dep_times
MATCH (stop) <- [:AT] - (arr:Arrival)
WITH arr, other, walking_time, dep_times, arr.time + walking_time AS new_arr_time
MERGE (new_arr:Arrival:Pedestrian {time: new_arr_time})
MERGE (new_arr) - [:AT] -> (other)
MERGE (arr) - [:TRAVEL {time:walking_time, mode: 'Pedestrian'}] -> (new_arr)
WITH new_arr, other, new_arr_time, REDUCE(s = HEAD(dep_times), x IN TAIL(dep_times) | CASE WHEN x < new_arr_time THEN s WHEN s < x THEN s ELSE x END) AS next_dep_time
WITH new_arr, other, next_dep_time, next_dep_time - new_arr_time AS wait_time
MATCH (other) <- [:AT] - (next_dep:Departure {time:next_dep_time})
MERGE (new_arr) - [:TRAVEL {time: wait_time, mode: 'Wait'}] -> (next_dep)
```

Okay, so that takes care of the basic transfers. This model assumes, btw, that if you are going to switch between bus or train "lines", that you will model them as separate stops (with walking times of 0 if they really are the same place is fine, but it's much more complicated to track if you share `:Stop`s). Now to take care of more complicated transfers, which were formerly modelled as switching to `:Pedestrian`, traveling, and then switching back:

```
MATCH (stop:Stop:Bus) - [r1:SWITCH_TO] -> (:Stop:Pedestrian) - [r2:CONNECTED_TO] -> (:Stop:Pedestrian) - [r3:SWITCH_TO] -> (other:Stop)
WITH stop, other, other.departure_times AS dep_times, REDUCE(s = 0 , x IN [r1, r2, r3] | s + COALESCE(x.travelTime, x.switchTime) ) AS walking_time
MATCH (stop) <- [:AT] - (arr:Arrival)
WITH arr, other, dep_times, walking_time, arr.time + walking_time AS new_arr_time
MERGE (new_arr:Arrival:Pedestrian {time:new_arr_time})
MERGE (new_arr) - [:AT] -> (other)
MERGE (arr) - [:TRAVEL {time:walking_time, mode: 'Pedestrian'}] -> (new_arr)
WITH new_arr, new_arr_time, other, REDUCE(s = HEAD(dep_times), x IN TAIL(dep_times) | CASE WHEN x < new_arr_time THEN s WHEN s < x THEN s ELSE x END) AS next_dep_time
WITH new_arr, other, next_dep_time, next_dep_time - new_arr_time AS wait_time
MATCH (other) <- [:AT] - (next_dep:Departure {time:next_dep_time})
MERGE (new_arr) - [:TRAVEL {time: wait_time, mode: 'Wait'}] -> (next_dep)
```

That gives you the basic framework of weighted relationships to apply the `dijkstra` algorithm to your inter-stop movement. There may be some estimation to figure out which stops might give good results, and how to walk to/from them from/to a given point (see earlier statement re: modeling all discrete space), but if you can pinpoint a `:Departure` or `:Arrival` node to begin at (or a few candidates), and a `:Stop` node for the other end of your query:

```
MATCH (:Stop {stopName: {begin_id} }) <- [:AT] - (d:Departure {time: {depart_time} })
WITH d
MATCH (end:Stop {stopName: {end_id} })
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstraWithDefaultWeight(d, end, 'TRAVELS>|AT>', 'time', 0) YIELD path, weight
RETURN path
```

Comment: Hey, first of all: Very interessting concept, I can see you spent quite some time for your answer! I am new to graphdatabases at all and did not thought about a solution like this! Thank you for your ideas!
I tried your code and got an error in the second last query: "Cannot merge node using null property value for time". I understand whats going wrong but I cannot find the error.

Comment: ...and: If I do the last query: MATCH (:Stop {stopName: {begin_id} }) <- [:AT] - (d:Departure {time: {depart_time} })
I have to know the exact departure time, correct? How can I choose the next available departure time? I know that I could simply look for a higher departure time but that would also match the 2nd or 3rd next departure...

Comment: This was a really fun question! So your second comment is easier: You do need to find the next available `:Departure` yourself, and that's what `REDUCE(s = HEAD(dep_times), x IN TAIL(dep_times) | CASE WHEN x < arrival_time THEN s WHEN s < x THEN s ELSE x END)` is for (apologies for unclear earlier version). It will pick the single closest time that is greater than a given time, which will allow you to calculate how long until your bus takes off from the query.

Comment: Ha! There is no transitTime in the relations, just travelTime (CONNECTED_TO), switchTime (SWITCH_TO) and time (TRAVEL). If I execute

    MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n.transitTime) RETURN n

the result is (no rows). No, there is no additional information

Comment: To your first response. Ok, than I have to add this REDUCE operation to the last query. Ok, I will try.. :)

Comment: my bad, that was a typo on my part. It is fixed now :)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I dont want to annoy you but I get an error in the last query: Failed to call procedure `apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode :: NODE?, endNode :: NODE?, relationshipTypesAndDirections :: STRING?, weightPropertyName :: STRING?) :: (path :: PATH?, weight :: FLOAT?)`: RELATIONSHIP[303] has no property with propertyKey="time".

Relationship 303 is the last 'AT' ending in the end node. At the moment I dont unterstand everything and it would help to see the results... ;)

Comment: The procedure you will want it `dijkstraWithDefaultWeight`, as edited above. This can be dangerous, because it will hide data inconsistencies, but it is the quickest alternative for you right now. For the future I would refactor all of the `[:AT]` relationships to to have a `time` property of 0, but this should let you get a path at least.

Comment: Hmm, this is really nice but it seems to be too much effort to create new stops "on the fly" in the case of car sharing or pooling... Is there a way to develop this in Java? In the simplest case it could be just one shortest path but with an intelligent cost function? Instead of using fix values using a function to calculate the cost of one specific edge? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're starting to transcend discrete modeling when you add that many dynamic elements. You can try implementing something in Java (maybe take `apoc`'s dijkstra as a guide, source [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/0183f4caaf2a5a48bcdfd4d057af957c3dd76200/src/main/java/apoc/algo/PathFinding.java)), but I don't know how well this problem matches a property graph at that point...